# How do I use a servo in an interrupt?

Tags: arduino-uno

I am working on a small circuit now where I increment the rotation of a servo motor and at the same time blink a LED.

I have used all methods I know to do it but still it does not work or it blinks and then the servo start working but never both at the same time.
This is what i am basically working with:

```
  for(position=0;position<=90;position=position+5){
    digitalWrite(led_pin,HIGH);
    delay(200);
    digitalWrite(led_pin,LOW);
    delay(200);
    servoBar.write(position);
    delay(15);
  }
```

But it blinks once and then it stops and the servo start working right after that.

I know I must not use delays in interrupts. I am using a function that I can but just to show you what I am working with.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the delay routine is blocking. It stops operation and blocks other things from happening. Have a look at the Blink without delay example in the example tab. (also linked below)
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay

What you need to do is to not block. Call the time checker often and check if the time you want delayed has run out. The perform the action needed to be done at that time.

This is a more sophisticated way to deal with timed events. Also look at this
**Demonstration code for several things at the same time.**
https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=223286.0

Have fun learning. :)

Comment: If you want the timing mechanics of the interrupt, you'd want to create very slim `loop()` routine that only checks if your custom "move the servo" flag is set. If it is, remove the flag and move the servo, and use the interrupt only to set the flag.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to manage timing without delay is to use:

```
if(millis()-lastCheck > delayPeriod){
lastCheck=millis();
doStuffHereOrChangeServo();
}
```

This code is naturally overflow-safe and is actually how delay() works. **The difference is that delay() uses a while() loop that breaks when this condition is met, so it prevents any code after the delay from running UNTIL delay completes. That's why you are getting odd pauses in your code.**

As a side note, it's actually a fun project to build a simple task scheduler that uses a list of function pointers and a variation on this method to do completely generic scheduling. If you want to try that route, you'd keep a struct holding the function pointer and a *signed* integer larger than your maximum intended delay size. Then, every time the scheduler is called, you subtract the difference between millis() and the stored value of millis() from each of those integers in the struct. Once that goes negative or zero, the task can run!